# Checking the Online Statuses of Multiple Websites Simultaneously

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, httprequest, monitoring

I need some help with a basic PowerShell script that sends a 200 HTTP request to a website to check if it's online. I have a script that checks one website, but I need to update it in order to check multiple websites every time it runs. I need to check 8-10 websites at a time.

Thanks.

Here is my script so far:

```
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.com')

$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Site is OK!"
}
Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
}

If ($HTTP_Response -eq $null) { } 
Else { $HTTP_Response.Close() }
```

I tried a few things. Added another HTTP_Request line, added another set of parentheses with the URL. I'm a complete novice when it comes to PowerShell, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: in powershell core you can leverage `ForEach-Object -Parallel`, in Windows PowerShell the easiest way to go about this is to install `ThreadJob` or use `GetResponseAsync()`

Comment: for checking 8-10 URLs you dont really need parallelism, you can just use a linear loop it shouldnt take more than a few seconds. its not clear what exactly you need help with

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create an array of addresses and then loop through them. I'm not great with powershell syntax but something like...

```
    $websites = @("www.google.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.microsoft.com")

foreach ($site in $websites) {
    Test-Connection $site -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($?) {
        Write-Host "$site is up"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$site is down"
    }
}
```